# Why double negative regex matches when positive one doesn't?

Tags: regular-expression

I have this regex

```
\%(\w\|[^[:punct:][:space:]]\|\%(\\\\\)*\\\)\%#\|\%#\%(\w\|[^[:space:][:punct:]]\)
```

What I wanted to is where this regex matches word characters `\w` match word characters except `u` and `b` so I've changed all `\w` to `[^\Wub]`

```
\%([^\Wub]\|[^[:punct:][:space:]]\|\%(\\\\\)*\\\)\%#\|\%#\%([^\Wub]\|[^[:space:][:punct:]]\)
```

But somehow in this line new regex matches `e` character.

```
name=decode_header(file_name_info)[0][0].replace(),
                                               ^
```

And old one doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

`\W` isn't understood as a character class inside a collection, so `[^\Wub]` is specifying

> Match any character other than `\`, `W`, `u`, and `b`.

See [`:help /[`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#/collection) for the specifics about what can be used inside a collection.